# Is there a .NET performance counter to show the rate of p/invoke calls being made?

Tags: .net, performance, interop, pinvoke, analysis

Is there a .NET performance counter to show the rate of p/invoke calls made?  I've just noticed that the application I'm debugging was making a call into native code from managed land within a tight loop.  The intended implementation was for a p/invoke call to be made once and then cached.  I'm wondering if I could have noticed this mistake via a CLR Interop or Remoting .NET performance counter.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the ".NET CLR Interop" for "# of marshalling" performance counter.

See this article for more http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998551.aspx.

Comment: Many of the pinvoke calls don't have parameters to be marshaled; Do you know if the "# of marshalling" counter is affected then?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't used it enough to know for sure.